# Можно ли через CSS обратится при hover к родителю ?

Tags: css3

Можно ли через CSS обратится при hover к родителю ?

То есть мне надо сделать, что-то типа

```
 .fw_like_wrap:hover  < .one_post{}
.one_post  .fw_like_wrap:hover   .one_post{}
```

Comment: @Камаз, для интереса, a 

.one_post:nth-child(1):hover{} 

не пробовали (может та и ошибаюсь)?

Comment: nth-child к ребенку прводит, а мне надо наоборот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. Описания такого селектора нет в [спеках](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). Придётся делать на JS.